# Stop SBT Native Packager writing to /etc/<app>

Tags: scala, sbt-native-packager

I am using the SBT Native Packager to build RPMs from a Scala project (written using Play Framework).

The documentation for SBT Native Packager says:

> If you include a conf/ directory with configuration, this will show up as a symlink under /etc/app/

How do I stop it creating this symlink? /etc/app/ will already exist, and I'm going to supply config with a file generated by puppet instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work (in my build.sbt):

```
linuxPackageSymlinks <<= (linuxPackageSymlinks) map (_ => Seq.empty[LinuxSymlink])
```

I believe the `<<=` is an override operator. This should just be replacing the 'list of symlinks to create' with an empty list before they have a chance to be created.